# Scroll to the contrary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
n=int(input())

from math import *

while n!=0:
     print (n,"\t",log10(n))
     n=n-1
```

Its output is:

```
10   1.0
9    0.9542425094393249
8    0.9030899869919435
7    0.8450980400142568  
6    0.7781512503836436
5    0.6989700043360189 
4    0.6020599913279624
3    0.47712125471966244
2    0.3010299956639812
1    0.0
```

I want it to be:

```
1    0.0
2    0.3010299956639812
3    0.47712125471966244
4    0.6020599913279624
5    0.6989700043360189
.
.
.
9    0.9542425094393249
10   1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n=int(input())

from math import*

for i in range(1,n+1):

     print (i,"\t",log10(i))
```

Comment: I'd use `range(n)`, then `print(i + 1, log10(i + 1), sep='\t')`.